# Paste method of worksheet class failed

Tags: vba, excel

Please consider the following Excel VBA code

```
 Private Sub Copy_Formula(Dest As Integer, iCustomer As Long)
  Sheets("INPUT").Select
  Cells(2, Dest).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range(Cells(4, Dest), Cells(3 + iCustomer, Dest)).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste '<------ Errors out
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Calculate
  Range(Cells(4, Dest), Cells(3 + iCustomer, Dest)).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End Sub
```

When this sub is called, value of Dest is 84 and iCustomer is 1044770.

I was just wondering if there is a solution to solve this paste operation? Is it possible to increase the buffer size somewhere to accommodate this massive data? We are using 32 bit Excel 2010 on a 32 GB RAM machine with a 64 bit OS.

Would a 64 bit Excel work?

Comment: I tried your code up to the line which you say is crashing, and it worked.  I just had a formula of `=A2` in the cell being copied.  (Excel 2013 32-bit 16Gb RAM)

Comment: Could it be possible that's its failing because of sheer amount of data? The text file from which I imported this sheet is 560 MB. If that's the case, can you please some other way?

Comment: You could try `Range(Cells(4, Dest), Cells(3 + iCustomer, Dest)).FormulaR1C1 = Cells(2, Dest).FormulaR1C1` - that **might** be less stressful on memory, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Always better to use fully qualified names instead of `ActiveSheet`.

Try this

```
 Private Sub Copy_Formula(Dest As Integer, iCustomer As Long)
  Sheets("INPUT").Cells(2, Dest).Copy Sheets("INPUT").Range(Cells(4, Dest), Cells(3 + iCustomer, Dest))
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Calculate

  Sheets("INPUT").Range(Cells(4, Dest), Cells(3 + iCustomer, Dest)).Copy

  Sheets("INPUT").Range(Cells(4, Dest), Cells(3 + iCustomer, Dest)).Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial _
                            Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
 End Sub
```

Also 32 or 64 bit, its all the same for this code.

Comment: Hi, thank you for sending the modified code. Unfortunately, it pops up displaying Copy method of Range class  failed. Any other suggestions

Comment: hmm works for me. not sure whats happening. Put this much code in a new rokbbok, rename a sheet as INPUT and test.

Comment: Always better to use the `Worksheets` collection when retrieving `Worksheet` objects ;-) ...and `Sheets` is implicitly referring to the active workbook too, so it's just *semi-qualified* ;0)

Comment: Could it be possible that's its failing because of sheer amount of data? The text file from which I imported this sheet is 560 MB. If that's the case, can you please some other way?

Comment: @cyboashu In the task manager I noticed that excel is taking 1.8 GB. Since its the 32 bit version, I am guessing that it doesn't have sufficient memory to perform the paste operation. I think with a 64 bit version, it might just work. Thoughts?